# Are there nouns that embody adjectives+verbs? (Not asking about attributive nouns)

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

I'm not sure if there's a better way for me to word my question. I've sorted through "noun" + "adjective" search results here on SE, but found nothing approximating what I'm after.

I'm trying to think of an example of a word that means something like "person/role who is so closely associated with adjective X that there is a specific word for such a person/role". In other words, it's a noun that's the quintessence of an adjective + verb combination. In particular, I'm after adjectives closely related to emotional states, but with nuances about behavior — such as "uninhibited" in the context of being direct and not backing down when challenged about one's wishes.

For example, "person who is courageous". Which I can't think of a noun for. Edit: I found one! *Braver* is an adjective-verb ("exhibiting greater courage; facing danger/pain/fear courageously"), and a noun ("one who acts bravely"); where the noun is so closely tied to the adjective and verb senses that it's an embodiment. This kind of noun is exactly what I'm looking for.

*Ingenue* is close to the type of word I'm looking for, as it's a noun closely associated with several characteristics — some of which are descriptive of personality or emotions.

For comparison, consider "person who repels enemy attacks" as being *defender*. (What I'd describe as a verb giving rise to a noun.)

We have these kinds of words for psychological states in some cases (e.g. "manic" for someone with very high energy, erratic behavior — which is indicative of psychological struggles), in which the word seems to be a mix of noun, adjective, and verb. That is, we can say "She is a manic." or "She is manic." — and be referring to an idea of a type of person: a description of what someone is (noun; medical term), a description of what someone does (verb; actions), and a description of the type of behavior they have (adjective; degree).

Words like "paladin" may be associated with specific adjectives, but they don't seem to *embody* them — which is what I'm after.

Does anyone know of any, or better yet what the term for them is? Or does anyone know of a site that has lists of them, or a way to search for them?

(Thanks to RegDwigнt for the punctuation standardization. This is my first time visiting the site.)

Comment: *"a person who* ***defends*** *against enemy attacks"* => ***defender***: nominalization of a verb, or deverbal nouns. You might be interested in morphology. Or perhaps more specifically, lexical word-formation.

Comment: It's not that simple. There are nouns with very specific meanings, some compositional, like _axe-murderer,_ but most having varying degrees of specificity. A good example is the English [verbs of cutting](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cutting.pdf), [verbs of cooking](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/cookingverbs.html) or [verbs of motion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/verbs.of.motion.html). They have many different dimensions of variation, some of which you may consider "adjectives". Really, though, this is lexical semantics, not combinations of "adjectives+verbs".

Comment: I kept thinking about "person who is courageous" and remembered an old Final Fantasy game. It had the word "braver" in it (see edit above) - which turns out to be exactly the kind of thing I was thinking of. Does that help clarify what I'm after, or bring to mind any resources I could use to find similar words?

Thanks for the term "deverbal", and the links to the pdfs. I'll check them all out.